# WPF Textbox style for default ContextMenu using custom MenuItem control template and style with image and text buttons will not close

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, contextmenu

I know there are many posts dealing with this topic, but none that address my specific need.  I want to define an override to the default style of the WPF Textbox ContextMenu.  My application is global with user defined multi-language.  That means all the literals in my app are really buttons and the user can enable a setting which allows a button click to display a dialog to enter the text for different languages.  This works throughout my app including other ContextMenus.  However, my solution for the Textbox context menu does everything right but will not close when the button is pressed.  How can I get the buttons in the MenuItem style/template to close the Context Menu?  Here is the style for the ContextMenu.

```
<Style x:Key="MyContextMenuStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource MyPopupBackgroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource MyBorderBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
                <Border x:Name="Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="1"
                            CornerRadius="6" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Margin="4,4,4,4">
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="MyMenuItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ctls:MyMenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="StaysOpenOnClick" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF494949"/>
    <Setter Property="ButtonImageSource" Value="{StaticResource EditBlue}" />
    <Setter Property="MaxImageSize" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="ButtonText" Value="Text" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ctls:MyMenuItem}">
                <Grid Margin="0,2,0,0">
                    <ctls:MyBasicButton Style="{StaticResource MyImageAndTextButtonStyle}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="16"
                        ButtonName="{TemplateBinding ButtonName}"
                        CollectionKey="{TemplateBinding CollectionKey}"
                        Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding ButtonText}" 
                        CanUseAlternateText="{TemplateBinding CanUseAlternateText}"
                        Image="{TemplateBinding ButtonImageSource}"
                        MaxImageSize="{TemplateBinding MaxImageSize}"
                        Command="{Binding Path=Command, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                    </ctls:MyBasicButton>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

---

Here is the resource for the ContextMenu template.

```
<system:String x:Key="CopyString">Copy</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="CutString">Cut</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="PasteString">Paste</system:String>

    <ContextMenu x:Key="CutCopyPasteContextMenu" Style="{StaticResource MyContextMenuStyle}">
        <ctls:MyMenuItem Style="{StaticResource MyMenuItemStyle}"
            Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut" InputGestureText=""
            StaysOpenOnClick="False"
            ButtonImageSource="{StaticResource CutBlue}"
            ButtonText="{Binding Source={StaticResource CutString}, Converter={StaticResource StringToMenuItemText}}">
        </ctls:MyMenuItem>
        <ctls:MyMenuItem Style="{StaticResource MyMenuItemStyle}"
            Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" InputGestureText=""
            StaysOpenOnClick="False"
            ButtonImageSource="{StaticResource CopyBlue}"
            ButtonText="{Binding Source={StaticResource CopyString}, Converter={StaticResource StringToMenuItemText}}">
        </ctls:MyMenuItem>
        <ctls:MyMenuItem Style="{StaticResource MyMenuItemStyle}"
            Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste" InputGestureText=""
            StaysOpenOnClick="False"
            ButtonImageSource="{StaticResource PasteBlue}"
            ButtonText="{Binding Source={StaticResource PasteString}, Converter={StaticResource StringToMenuItemText}}">
        </ctls:MyMenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>
```

I have a custom MenuItem control with dependency properties that support binding between my custom Button control and the MenuItem.  Here is that code.

```
public class MyMenuItem : MenuItem
    {
        public string ButtonName
        {
            get { return (string)base.GetValue(ButtonNameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ButtonNameProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonNameProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonName", typeof(string), typeof(MyMenuItem));

        public string ButtonText
        {
            get { return (string)base.GetValue(ButtonTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ButtonTextProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonTextProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonText", typeof(string), typeof(MyMenuItem));
        public ImageSource ButtonImageSource
        {
            get { return GetValue(ButtonImageSourceProperty) as ImageSource; }
            set { SetValue(ButtonImageSourceProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonImageSourceProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(MyMenuItem));

        public double MaxImageSize
        {
            get { return (double)base.GetValue(MaxImageSizeProperty); }
            set { base.SetValue(MaxImageSizeProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxImageSizeProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("MaxImageSize", typeof(double), typeof(MyMenuItem));

        public string CollectionKey
        {
            get { return (string)base.GetValue(CollectionKeyProperty); }
            set { base.SetValue(CollectionKeyProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CollectionKeyProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("CollectionKey", typeof(string), typeof(MyMenuItem));

        public bool CanUseAlternateText
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(CanUseAlternateTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CanUseAlternateTextProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CanUseAlternateTextProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("CanUseAlternateText", typeof(bool), typeof(MyMenuItem));

    }
```

Finally, Here is the style for my Textbox using my custom ContextMenu named CutCopyPasteContextMenu.

```
<Style x:Key="MyTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource MyDataLabelBackgroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MyTextBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="CaretBrush" Value="{DynamicResource MyTextBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{DynamicResource MySelectedBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource MyMainFont}" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="28"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,4,0"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource MyBorderBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="Continue"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay"  Value="2000"/>
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.BetweenShowDelay"  Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowDuration"  Value="60000"/>
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled"  Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource CutCopyPasteContextMenu}"/>
        
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="4" 
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false"
                                      Margin="4,-1,0,0"
                                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                                          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource MyDisabledBackgroundBrush}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsReadOnly" Value="false"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource MyBorderHighlightBrush}"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource MyBorderHighlightBrush}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Here is what the ContextMenu looks like when the app is run.  All the menu item functions work correctly and I am allowed to define the dynamic language text for the menu item buttons as I designed.

[image: Here is what the ContextMenu looks like when the app is run.]

Can someone please tell me why the ContextMenu will not close?  I think it might have something to do with my Button control absorbing the click event of the MenuItem but I am just guessing.